# Which rails version (among rails 3.x.x) is more relevant for upgradation of rails 2.3.11 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an rails 2.3.11 project, this project have assm , act_as_version, act_as_tree, gruff.... etc around 25 pluggins. this project has 153 models and around 130 controllers, I have to upgrade my project in rails 3.x.x.

Which version of rails 3.x.x I have to use in upgradation of my project??

Comment: You need to provide more information. Why do you need to upgrade to Rails 3? What features do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Whichever version you want.... If you need certain services that Rails 3.2 provides, do that. If you just need services that Rails 3.1 provides (like asset pipeline) use that. Or just use 3.0 to keep it simple. Keep in mind that the higher the version the more changes you will have to make.

BTW 153 models and 130 controllers? This sounds like something gone horribly wrong.